# Как в Python вызвать метод другого класса?

Tags: python, django

При вызове `create()` в `SomeAPI`:

```
class SomeAPI(mixins.UpdateModelMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
   permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

   def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       print ("someapi")
       SomeClass.somefunc(request, args, kwargs)
       return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

class SomeClass():   
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

    def somefunc(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.data)
        ...
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
   Exception Value: tuple object has no attribute data
```

Comment: Надо создать объект класса `obj = SomeClass()`, а затем уже: `obj.somefunc(request, args, kwargs)`

Comment: @Wolkodav спасибо, сделал вывод, что мне нужен синглтон, чтобы каждый раз не создавать объект. Либо вот ниже про статические методы подсказывают

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из кода, необходимо надо создать экземпляр класса SomeClass

```
SomeClass().somefunc(request, args, kwargs)
```

Т.е мы создаем объект и вызываем его функцию

**UPD**

Для использования без создания класса необходимо определить как статических  метод:

```
class SomeClass():   
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

    @staticmethod
    def somefunc(request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.data)
        ...
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. А если somefunc()  класса SomeClass будет вызываться из разных других классов, можно ли создать объект класса SomeClass глобально, что ли, чтобы каждый раз не создавать новый? Т.к. этот SomeClass служит для работы с базой данных. Или это корректно каждый раз при вызове использовать SomeClass().somefunc() ?

Comment: Для того чтоб не делать так постоянно, почитайте о статических методах_)